# drag and drop in datatable not working on next second page correct position not updating in database

Tags: php, jquery

I am using drag and drop jquery code for datatable. My drag and drop for row first(1) 10 recorders working correctly in datatable when move on next page second(2) it's not working correctly. On the second page of datatable row not drag and drop correctly and in database position column not updating correctly its make column position with value 1 on second page.
my problem now how to update position column in datatable on all pages first, second, third so on...

i have tried to change position with 
`$value['position'] = ('$pages_row * $page_size) + $key`;

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() { 
  var $sortable = $( "#athlete-class-datatable-responsive > tbody " );

  $sortable.sortable({
      stop: function ( event, ui ) {
          var parameters = $sortable.sortable( "toArray" );
           alert(parameters);
           var url = '/godspeed/Athlete_class/updatePositions';
          $.post(url,{value:parameters},function(result){
              alert(result);
          });
      }
  });
  });
</script>
```

controller

```
  public function updatePositions() {  
foreach ($_POST["value"] as $key => $value) {          
     $data["position"] = $key; // i am unable to change position on next page 
       $this->Athlete_classes->updatePosition($data,$value);
     }
echo "Sorting Done";
 }
```

model

```
function updatePosition($data,$id){
    if(array_key_exists("from", $data)){
        $data["from"]=$this->real_escape_string($data["from"]);
    }
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $value="'$value'";
        $updates[]="$key=$value";
    }
        $imploadAray =  implode(",", $updates);
                  $query=$this->db->query("Update dev_athlete_class SET $imploadAray Where id='$id'");
}
```

my html code is

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="athlete-class-datatable-responsive"> 
                    <!--<table  id="athlete-class-datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap bulk_action" cellspacing="0" width="100%">-->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="no-sort" style="width: 30px;" ><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat check_all" data-check="athlete_class_list" ></th>
                               <th>id</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>From Time</th>
                                <th>To Time</th>
                                <th class="no-sort" style="width: 50px;text-align: center;" >Edit</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($data['Exercise_multiplier_datas'] as $key => $value) { ?>
                                <!--<tr>-->
                           <tr id="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>">
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="checkbox"    id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="flat athlete_class_list multiple_delete"></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $value["id"]; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $value["position"]; ?></td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $value['from']; ?></td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $value['to']; ?></td>
                                    <!--<td style="width:4%"><img src="<php echo  base_url() ?>assets<php echo $value['image']; ?>" class="user_image_athlete_level_image" style="width:70px;height:70px"></td>-->
                                   <td style="text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;"><a href="#/pencil-square-o" class="edit_Athlete_class option_icon" data-json='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($value, TRUE), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>'  data-block="school_form_block" data-form="school_form" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>

                                  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value["id"]; ?>" id="item" name="item">
                                </tr> 
                             <?php } ?>

                        </tbody>


                    </table>
```

my datatable is like that
on the sencod page its show position id 10 same id show

```
id | from    | to    | position 
1    18:00    19:00      1
2    20:00    21:00      2
3    18:00    22:00      3
4    12:00    23:00      4
5    18:00    24:00      5
6    12:00    25:00      6
7    18:00    26:00      7
8    12:00    27:00      8
9    18:00    28:00      9
10   12:00    29:00      10
11   18:00    19:00      1
12   12:00    01:00      2
```

I want an actual result in datatable like this with current position id

```
id | from    | to    | position 
1    18:00    19:00      1
2    20:00    21:00      2
3    18:00    22:00      3
4    12:00    23:00      4
5    18:00    24:00      5
6    12:00    25:00      6
7    18:00    26:00      7
8    12:00    27:00      8
9    18:00    28:00      9
10   12:00    29:00      10
11   18:00    19:00      11
12   12:00    01:00      12
```

Comment: Is a request being sent when you drag and drop on the second page?

Comment: yes, sir sent on 10 rows ids every time on first page sent id 1,2.3,4,5.6,7,8,9,10 and on send page sent ids 11,12
but its position id i am unable to change on second send page